# How to find overlap between time intervals without date part

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have to find out the overlap between 2-time ranges and it does not include date part in comparison but time only e.g range_1 is 9AM-6PM and range_2 is 5PM-8AM. The actual times are in 24-hour format. I have written a solution that finds the overlap but it does not work when any of the time is in cross-day/after-midnight time for example 10PM-2AM

Both the times are of the same day but my current solution does not work correctly when the comparison has to make for any time after midnight. For example, it gives correct output in case of range_1: 9AM-6PM and range_2: 5PM-8PM, gives output 5PM-6PM overlap that's correct but cannot find overlap in case range_1: 10PM-2AM and range_2: 1AM-3AM same day.
Following is the link to my codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NZOqJm?editors=0010

```
    function overlap(t1,t2)
    {
    var timeFormat = "hh:mm";
    let t1from = moment(t1.timeFrom,timeFormat);
    let t1to = moment(t1.timeTo,timeFormat);

    let t2from = moment(t2.timeFrom,timeFormat);
    let t2to = moment(t2.timeTo,timeFormat);

    let overlapFrom = null;
    let overlapTo = null;


    if (t2from.isBetween(t1from, t1to) && t2to.isBetween(t1from, t1to)) {
        //complete overlap
        overlapFrom = t2from;
        overlapTo = t2to;
    }
  else if (t1from.isBetween(t2from, t2to) && t1to.isBetween(t2from, t2to))
    {
       overlapFrom = t1from;
        overlapTo = t1to;
    }
    else if (t2from.isBetween(t1from, t1to)) {
        overlapFrom = t2from;
        overlapTo = t1to;
    }
    else if (t2to.isBetween(t1from, t1to)) {
        overlapFrom = t1from;
        overlapTo = t2to;
    }            

    let doesOverlap = overlapFrom !== null && overlapTo !== null;
    let response = {
        doesOverlap: doesOverlap,
        overlapingMinutes: doesOverlap ?  Math.abs(moment.duration(overlapFrom.diff(overlapTo)).asMinutes()): 0,
        overlapFrom,
        overlapTo
    }
    return response;

    }


/*let t1 = {
  timeFrom:'22:00',
  timeTo:'02:00'
}


let t2 = {
  timeFrom:'01:00',
  timeTo:'03:00'
}*/


let t1 = {
  timeFrom:'09:00',
  timeTo:'18:00'
}


let t2 = {
  timeFrom:'17:00',
  timeTo:'20:00'
}
console.log(overlap(t1,t2));
```

range_1: 10PM-2AM

range_2: 1AM-3AM

Correct Output Should be: 1 AM to 2 AM

As both of the times overlap, all the times are within the day and does not include any date. Consider it as 2 students study at these times daily, then what times of both if these overlaps

Comment: you may spilt every cross midnight(when start time > end time) into two and process them separately

Comment: Your first example (commented out) is inconsistent. Is it "10pm today to 3am tomorrow" or "10pm yesterday to 3am today"? Is second range (t2) refers to "today"? Either way the result should be either "10pm to 2pm" (not 3pm) or _none_.

Comment: Um, the overlap of 10PM-2AM and 1AM-3AM is 1AM-2AM ...

Comment: Do you always assume that the second range is after the first? Otherwise 22:00-02:00 will not overlap with 01:00-03:00. If the result of your first example is 22:00 to 03:00, that's joining the two ranges, not finding the overlap.

Comment: Assume the date part of the calculation yourself. If the end time is earlier than the start time, then you know that you need to add 1 day to your assumed end date.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just work with hours / minutes then:

```js
const smaller = (a, b) => a.hours < b.hours || (a.hours === b.hours && a.mins < b.mins);
const equals = (a, b) => a.hours === b.hours && a.mins === b.mins;

function overlap(a, b) {
  if(smaller(a.to, a.from)) {
    return [
      ...overlap({ from: { hours: 0, mins: 0}, to: a.to }, b),
      ...overlap({ from: a.from, to: { hours: 24, mins: 0 }}, b),
    ];
  }
  
  if(smaller(b.to, b.from)) {
    return [
      ...overlap(a, { from: { hours: 0, mins: 0}, to: a.to }),
      ...overlap(a, { from: a.from, to: { hours: 24, mins: 0 }}),
    ];
  }


  const result = {
    from: smaller(b.from, a.from) ? a.from : b.from,
    to: smaller(a.to, b.to) ? a.to : b.to,
  };
  
  return equals(result.from, result.to) ? [] : [result];
}




console.log(...[
  [
    { from: { hours: 6, mins: 10 }, to: { hours: 8, mins: 10 }},
    { from: { hours: 6, mins: 10 }, to: { hours: 8, mins: 10 }}
  ],  [
    { from: { hours: 7, mins: 10 }, to: { hours: 10, mins: 10 }},
    { from: { hours: 6, mins: 10 }, to: { hours: 8, mins: 10 }}
  ],  [
    { from: { hours: 23, mins: 10 }, to: { hours: 8, mins: 10 }},
    { from: { hours: 6, mins: 10 }, to: { hours: 8, mins: 10 }}
  ]
].map(([a, b]) => `${JSON.stringify(a)}\n overlaps with ${JSON.stringify(b)}\n in ${JSON.stringify(overlap(a, b))}\n\n`));
```

Comment: when i do overlap({ from: { hours: 22, mins: 10 }, to: { hours: 2, mins: 10 }}, { from: { hours: 1, mins: 10 }, to: { hours: 4, mins: 10 }})), it gives me 2 results, one is _1:10 to 2:10_ which is right, but it also gives _22:10 to 04:10_ which is wrong, thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of corner cases that need to be sorted out, like do
"10:00, 11:00" and "11:00, 12:00" overlap?  And is "10:00, 10:00" zero minutes or 24 hours?

In any case, the way I'd go about doing this is to convert the times to minutes past midnight and compare that. What this code does is that. The comparison is "is the start time of one duration 'between' the start/end times of the other", and, if not, swap the times and do the check again.

```
function overlap(t0, t1) {
    // convert time to minutes past midnight
    var minutes = (d) => {return Object.values(d).map(d => {
        d=d.split(':').map(d=>parseInt(d));
        return d[0]*60+d[1];
    })};
    // If the end time is before the start then add 24 hours to the end
    // time to wrap it into next day. start==end gets 24 hrs added.
    var nextday = (d) => {if(d[0]>=d[1])d[1]+=24*60;return d}
    t0 = nextday(minutes(t0));
    t1 = nextday(minutes(t1));
    var olap = (t0, t1) => {
        // beginning of t0 between begin/end of t1
        // or
        // end of t0 between begin/end of t1
        return (t0[0]>=t1[0] && t0[0]<=t1[1]) 
            || (t1[0]>=t0[0] && t1[0]<=t0[1]);
    }
    return olap(t0, t1) || olap(t1, t0)
}
```

Comment: for your question: 
* do "10:00, 11:00" and "11:00, 12:00" overlap ==> yes maybe 1 minute

* is "10:00, 10:00" zero minutes or 24 hours? ==> its 24 hours, as i said consider the case where a student studies 10:00 to 12:00 daily, theres no date in it, bcs its just time, we have to find overlap b/w 2 students' study time

Comment: Then the '>=' && '<=' (as written) are the correct comparisons.